# restcomm docker image installation on windows 8.1

Tags: docker, restcomm

I am trying to install Docker image of Restcomm on my windows 8.1 laptop by following http://www.telestax.com/rapid-webrtc-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker/.
I am able to install DOCKER and run the container Hello-world properly.

But when i run the command to create container... "docker run –name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS=”YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE” -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp gvagenas/restcomm"

i am getting the following error...
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c88fcab56034096e98ddcd71d1d2db17e5858b88c64b1859efcb86d740e3972c: failed to create endpoint restcomm on network bridge: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p udp -d 0/0 --dport 65116 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:65116 ! -i docker0:  (fork/exec /usr/local/sbin/iptables: cannot allocate memory)

Request for your help and suggestion and thanks in advance

Rgds
Ias

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem directly related to RestComm Docker image but to docker itself https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8539 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9139